# Error Writing Double Quotes to Csv Python CSV Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, character-encoding

I'm trying to write an output to csv using the csv writer module. I'm getting this
[Instead of double quotes (") I am getting this type of char (‚Äú)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRRvQ.png)

They should be like this
[The right output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHdFh.png)

My code (NOTE: I already tried adding `encoding='utf-8` in the `with open()` statement and even tried adding `.encoding('utf-8)` in looping the 'key' but still having the same wrong output.

My code:

```
with open('word_count.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = writer(f)
    for k,v in new_dict.items():
        csv_writer.writerow([k, v])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first encode the value of k,v and then add this to CSV.